# Django selectable don´t drops down autocomplete

Tags: django, autocomplete, jquery-ui-selectable

i'm using django-selectable and i'm getting nervous :|

models.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible    
class Filing(models.Model):


    company = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100,  null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=110, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True) 


    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker
```

lookups.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from selectable.base import LookupBase
from selectable.registry import registry
from .models import Filing

class CompanyLookup(LookupBase):

    model = Filing
    search_fields = ('company__icontains', )

registry.register(CompanyLookup)
```

So don't work :( but

other lookups.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from selectable.base import LookupBase
from selectable.registry import registry
from .models import Filing

class CompanyLookup(LookupBase):

    def get_query(self, request, ticker):
        data= Filing.objects.values_list('company',flat=True)      
        return [x for x in data if x.startswith(ticker)]


registry.register(CompanyLookup)
```

works, drops down, but only with the attributes of "startswith" and i need "icontains". Also don't work "istarswith", neither "contains":

In my consoles:

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf?      noCache=1491057317592
Request Method:GET 
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
```

and:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
 at jquery.dj.selectable.js?v=0.9.0:390
 (anonymous) @ jquery.dj.selectable.js?v=0.9.0:390




$(document).ready(function () {
    // Patch the django admin JS
    if (typeof(djselectableAdminPatch) === "undefined" || djselectableAdminPatch) {
        djangoAdminPatches();
    }
    // Bind existing widgets on document ready
    if (typeof(djselectableAutoLoad) === "undefined" || djselectableAutoLoad) {
        window.bindSelectables('body');
    }
});
})(jQuery || grp.jQuery);    <------ this is the line 390
```

also i don't understand why because in the view source code the

```
 <script type="text/javascript"src="/static/javascript/jquery.dj.selectable.js"></script>
```

is loaded correctly

Thank you in advance if you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def get_query(self, request, ticker):
    return  list(Filing.objects.filter(company__icontains=ticker).values_list('company', flat=True))
```

You want to filter your data in your database. Not in Python. Your database is much faster. When you do `[x for x in x]` you are returning a list, no a queryset. You can filter your queryset in the database by putting `field__icontains=value` in the filter method of a queryset.